# Windows Edge webdriver fails with WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge, circleci, python-behave

I'm trying to run `behave` tests on Windows Edge in CircleCI, but even simple test fails initializing a session with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\circleci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\circleci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\circleci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\circleci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\circleci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 208, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error
```

#### Setup

I use standard CircleCI windows image [`windows-server-2019-vs2019:stable`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/hello-world-windows/#software-pre-installed-in-the-windows-image)

Install there Edge driver and try to start it as a service:

```
choco install -y jdk10 selenium-edge-driver selenium
```

Then I ssh to the machine for debugging and try

```
python -c "from selenium import webdriver; webdriver.Edge()"
```

This cause the error above. The path to the web-driver is correct, an incorrect causes another error.

#### Already tried

1. Turning off UAC (using cmd.exe):

```
reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v PromptOnSecureDesktop /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

2. Trying to connect using Chrome settings:

Stating the server by myself:

```
/c/tools/selenium/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
[14:48:13.545] - Listening on http://localhost:17556/
```

```
python -c "from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver; from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities; from selenium.webdriver.chrome.remote_connection import ChromeRemoteConnection; rwd = RemoteWebDriver(command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(remote_server_addr='http://localhost:17556', keep_alive=False))"
```

This results with a 401 error bad request or if I update `desired_capabilities` something like:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

3. Tried to change the Edge binary to the latest in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ but still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried stopping and re-starting your service?

Comment: What are your Microsoft Edge version and Microsoft Edge WebDriver version? On the [official docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#windows), it says *To run a job on a Windows machine, you must add the `windows` key to the top-level configuration for the job.* Besides, please pay attention to the [known issue](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/hello-world-windows/#known-issues) that *Connecting to a Windows job via SSH and using the `bash` shell results in an empty terminal prompt.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to install Edge on the CircleCI image. But if services like BrowserStack doesn't suit you, there is a way to run Selenium with Windows/Edge on your own/AWS machine deploying an official Vagrant image.

1. Download [official VM with Edge installed](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) (Vagrant will be fine)
2. If you plan to use AWS check [vagrant-aws](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) to deploy the image on EC2
3. Install Selenium on the Vagrant image. You can try to use Puppet for it, check [this example](https://github.com/p0deje/se-boxes), but it uses an outdated Edge version, you need to update [the manifest](https://github.com/p0deje/se-boxes/blob/master/environments/windows/manifests/edge.pp).
4. Spend some time on setting permissions/roles and other IAM stuff to be able to connect to the EC2 from CircleCI.
5. Now using `webdriver.Remote` you can connect to the Selenium (hub or stand alone) with Edge and a web-driver for it installed.